# I need to overwrite a run-time function js

Tags: javascript, function, overwrite

i need to overwrite a function that I take from a script, the function start like this:

```
(function (K) {
//code
})(window);
```

for a normal function it's easy:

```
function nameFun = function (params) {
//code
}
```

so now , how I can overwrite that function ?

Thank you

Comment: Within that function what is it setting on the `K` object? If it is setting anything then you can overwrite that by doing `window.whatever = yourNewFunction;`.

Comment: But with that I overwrite all the script ?

Comment: That depends on what is inside the body of that function. Could you post the body of it?

Comment: It's to much long, K is a object window
Can I make K.whatever = function(){} ?

Comment: It really depends... if all that statement does is assign a function to a property of `K` AKA `window`, then yes you can just overwrite the function with your own one. You might want to post the full function on pastebin or somewhere so we can get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xWJcH/

Comment: the function that I want to overwrite start at 16912 and end at 18559 and I need what the object checkout (row:21743)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can - it's an anonymous function that is immediately invoked, so it won't be stored on any object for you to overwrite. Even if it were stored somewhere, as it is invoked immediately you're not going to be able to overwrite the function with your own code before it's execution.

Comment: There is a way to take only a part of the script or a way to bypass this problem? (I need to overwrite because in that function there is an error)

Comment: @Scutto: Post the code that is in error and we might be able to help a little more.

Comment: this is the error: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage com.greensock.events.EventDispatcher] is not a function, it is object. (debug.js#17214)

this is the row: M = j.Ticker.prototype = new j.events.EventDispatcher();

Comment: This will probably just defer the problem, but you could say j.Events.EventDispatcher = function() {}

Answer (score 0):

If this function is written in separate js file, which is includes on page within `<script src="...">` tag, you can try to place inline js code just after this tag and remove it programmatically.

If not, you can simply wrap this code block in `try { ... } catch (e) { console.log(e); }`.

Comment: I am working in a Web Service and I need to load that script to take some data after the function thats in the WS makes an error. So I can decide to not load the script simply not write the function to don't load the script

Comment: So you need only partially overwrite target function?

Comment: I need to overwrite only partially the script, and leave the other function the same. I don't need to overwrite that function with some code, only makes the script like if that function don't exist